# Excel - Find all items that share a common cell value

Tags: excel, reference, lookup

I am wanting to search this list:

[image]

The goal is to determine what all is inside Basket 1, determine which item of those costs the most, and return the color of that specific item. My brain is having a hard time determining the right path for this.

Comment: I think you could use Pivot Tables. You can filter using TOP 10 (in your case it would be top 1)

Comment: Another option (apart from what @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns mentioned) would be to filter the **Basket** column and then arrange the **Amount** column in ascending or descending order to get your answer

Comment: So you want to return just `Yellow` in this specific case? Because it's the most expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a Pivot Table, you can resume data based on basket # and then filter by most valuable item, and get the color.

[image]

The set up for this Pivot Table is all fields into Rows Section, except `Amount` that will go into values.

[image]

**NOTE:** Even if my Excel language is different than yours, options I'm using should be in the same position. But anyways, besides set up from the image above, you need to apply a **value filter** (not label filter!), to field `ID` and make sure choose option **TOP 10** and set it to show just **TOP 1**

If you just want the **most expensive** item, ignoring Basket #, just remove field `Basket` from your Pivot Table, and it will work.

[image]

Actually you could have 2 Pivot Tables, each one set up in a different way (all baskets, or each basket).

Comment: Loving the demo! :)

Comment: A really beautiful answer!   YouTube-worthy!